# How is it possible to convert a std::vector<std::vector<double>> to a torch::Tensor?

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

I have a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` where I want to conver it into a `torch::Tensor` in libtorch. However it seems, the `torch::tensor()`, or `torch::from_blob()`, can't be used for this purpose!

I tried to use `c10::ArrayRef` and then use that for converting the data into a `torch::Tensor` by doing `c10::ArrayRef<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> res(myvecs)` but this also seems useless as I can't seem to find a way to convert it into `torch::Tensor`.

How should I go about this conversion in libtorch? What are my other options other than e.g:

```cpp
auto tensor = torch::zeros({ 46,85 });
for (size_t i = 0; i < 46; i++)
{
   for (size_t j = 0; j < 85; j++)
   {
       tensor[i][j] = probs[i][j];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the easiest way would be to use a simple `std::vector<double>` instead of a vector of vectors. You would have contiguous memory and `torch::from_blob` would work (as mentionned in the other answer).

If that is not possible/convenient, I suggest the following workaround. I assume that your vector is a `(n,m)` matrix (i.e all the `n` vectors have the same size `m`) :

```
int n = 5, m = 4;
// Just creating some dummy data for example
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect(n, std::vector<double>(m, 0)); 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        vect[i][j] = i+j;

// Copying into a tensor
auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(at::kDouble);
auto tensor = torch::zeros({n,m}, options);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    tensor.slice(0, i,i+1) = torch::from_blob(vect[i].data(), {m}, options);
```

Edit : you may need to add a call to `clone` in case where you cannot ensure that the vector will outlive the tensor (because `from_blob` do not take ownership, so its data will be erased when the vector is destroyed)

Comment: Thanks alot how does this compare to the simple for loop? is there any paralelization /optimization going on here? or are they just the same performance wise

Comment: Thanks got it. completely forgot about the `from_blob` that apparently. greatly appreciate it

Comment: Well, you would need a benchmark to be sure of that, but I believe it should be faster than a manually made for loop. Most torch operations rely on BLAS, which are much more efficient than anything you would do by hand (however this is a very simple operation : one vector copied in another, so BLAS optimization is not that big here). In addition to this, if you first copied the 2D vector in a 1D vector to then used `from_blob`, each element would be copied twice instead of only once in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. by the way, if I were to generalize your method for vectors of higher dimensions such as e.g shape = (1,2,4,6). in that case, how should I be going about it? should I first be flattening them into 1d and then go for from_blob?

Comment: In such situation, the easy generalization would be to loop over the first 3 dimensions (instead the 1 for loop I have here) and slice as I did here. However, I believe using vectors of vectors of vectors ... would get really ugly really fast, so you'd probably better think of using another data stucture, with contiguous memory. Like a flat 1D vector for example

Answer (score 3):

I have not used any of the libraries that you mention, but if I should guess then the libraries probably expect a continuous array and not small segments of memory scattered around the heap.

So convert the `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` to `std::vector<double>` and pass the `vec.data()` pointer to `torch`

```
std::vector<double> linearize(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& vec_vec) {
    std::vector<double> vec;
    for (const auto& v : vec_vec) {
        for (auto d : v) {
            vec.push_back(d);
        }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciate your time and kind response