# Convert C++ vector<vector<float>> to torch::tensor

Tags: torch, torchscript

I am trying to convert my c++ vector to a torch tensor. However, my code is returning incorrect conversions.

```
    cout << history << endl;
    auto options1 = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat32);
    input = torch::from_blob(history.data(), {size, 1, 6}, options1).to(torch::kFloat32);

    cout << input << endl;
```

The above code returns the following output:

> -9 -3 -3 -12 -0 -0 -12 -2 -3 -12 -0 -0

```
(1,.,.) = 
 -9.8681e-32  4.5793e-41 -9.8682e-32  4.5793e-41 -9.8682e-32  4.5793e-41




(2,.,.) = 
 -9.8682e-32  4.5793e-41 -9.8683e-32  4.5793e-41 -9.8683e-32  4.5793e-41




[ CPUFloatType{2,1,6} ]
```

Comment: What is the type of `history`? Is it `std::vector<int>` ?

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466847/how-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-stdvectorstdvectordouble-to-a-torchten), it works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can not convert a 2D vector or more dimension to Tensor with the `from_blob()` method, but you can use this method to overcome the problem:

```
vector<float> linearize(const vector<vector<float>>& vec_vec) {
    vector<float> vec;
    for (const auto& v : vec_vec) {
        for (auto d : v) {
            vec.push_back(d);
        }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

And, in this way, you can convert it to Tensor (m,n width and height of vector):

```
vector<float> vec = linearize(your2Dvector);
torch::Tensor t = torch::from_blob(vec.data(), {n,m});
```